# How to reload a page in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reload

How to reload a page in react-native.

In reactjs window.location.reload() worked but it is not supported in react native.

It throws exception - *Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined*

Comment: can you explain why you want to reload a page?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is a browser feature, and not available in React Native.

Since React Native doesn't have a router itself, the answer depends on which one you use. Assuming you use React Router, the most popular one, you could do this:

```js
const history = useHistory();
history.replace(YOUR_ROUTE_HERE);
```